# Eexploring the applications of the SVD and PCA

Tags: linear-algebra

Hei, I am really trying to see *beyond* what is taught in math books. I am doing this just because I do love math! I just need some help with this one.

I have been working with *Singular Value Decomposition* and the *Principal Component Analysis*. I understand that this is an amazing tool (the PCA) working with images and chemometrics, in statistics and metamodeling.

But, is there any other areas where the *SVD* or *PCA* can be applied? If so, which are these areas? biology?, chemistry?

I read somewhere that the *PCA* could be combined with *Dynamical systems*, meaning that we could combined *PCA* or *SVD* with *Differential equations(!)*

I can read books and find papers, but I know that there are people in this forum which have a lot of knowledge and experience. May be someone has used the *SVD* in electronics or molecular science...... I was hoping you would feel sharing!

In advance thank you!

Comment: There are thousands of papers on the use of the SVD and the PCA. Just google them.